# What is the point of $sce?

Tags: angularjs

If you structure your front-end in such a way that Angular recompiling code on the front end is dangerous, which is what $sce tries to prevent to my understanding, can't an attacker just bypass all your $sce code by editing the HTML themself and calling $compile manually? Since every variable in the front-end can invariably be accessed at will, what does $sce actually protect against?

For example, what is the purpose of $sce.CSS? If a user really wants to alter the CSS, they can just insert a style element manually.

I might have missed that $sce is only meant to ensure the user won't break the application, and is not actually meant for security.

Comment: If someone edits the HTML manually, all they manage to hack is themselves. `$sce` is there to prevent hacking *others*.

Comment: So you would mainly call it on HTML you get from a server call then?

Comment: That is the most common use case for $sce, I have seen. It would be interesting to know if someone has used it in other scenarios as well